# Is it always possible to go to synchronous coordinate (Gaussian normal coordinates) by coordinate transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In general Lorentzian spacetime, Riemann metric is general rank-2 tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. On the other hand, in synchronous coordinate(Gaussian normal coordinate), metric can be written like 
$$ds^2=-dt^2+g_{ij}dx^idx^j. \quad (i,j=1,2,3)$$
Is it always possible to transform the metric in this form by coordinate transformation?

I also want to know whether the above statement holds in the case of the metric like this form;
$$ds^2=-g_{00}dt^2+g_{ij}dx^idx^j. \quad (i, j=1,2,3)$$

Anyway, my question is "whether or not we can separate time and space in general spacetime **globally** (not local inertial frame)?".

I guess it is possible, since the degrees of freedom of coordinate transformation is 4, and the number of metric component I want to fix is 4 ...$(g_{00},g_{01},g_{02},g_{03})$. This is very rough estimate, so it may be wrong.

Comment: Are the metric components $g_{ij}$ and $g_{00}$ allowed to have explicit $t$ dependence? If not, then $\partial_t$ is a timelike Killing vector field, which a generic spacetime does not have.

Comment: Thanks for a comment. I assume the case that the metric components can have t dependence.

Comment: If your spacetime is not time orientable, there will be a global obstruction to finding Gaussian normal coordinates on a spacelike slice.  I would think this is the main obstruction on a single slice.  The Gaussian normal coordinates will generically break down in a finite proper time from the initial slice because they require the normal directions to be geodesic, and these generically will focus and form caustics due to curvature.

Comment: Thank you for a comment. Actually, when I saw the construction of gaussian normal coordinates, I supposed there is no reason that $g_{0i}$ equal to zero apart from the spacelike slice I chose first. In this viewpoint, could it be said that gaussian normal coordinates are some local normal coordinate such as inertial frame?

Comment: Yes, in principle, it is always possible to transform to a synchronous frame. It is discussed in detail in Landau & Lifshitz's section 97.